# past perfect tense and comma usage in Churchill's book

Tags: word-usage, tenses, commas

I'm reading a book called "My early life" by Winston Churchill.

"I was working in the saloon of the Indiaman, and had reached an exciting point in my story."

1) why did he put comma before "and had reached"? Is it because the tense was different from "I was..."

2) I'm confused of the order of these two events. So, he reached an exciting point and then he found himself working in the saloon? Or it's the opposite?

Thank you for reading this!

Comment: A seemingly easy to respond question but with a slight twist. Could you add the `past-perfect` tag in your question, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consulting pp. 211-213 of the [full text of Churchill's memoir](http://archive.org/stream/rovingcommissino001321mbp/rovingcommissino001321mbp_djvu.txt) reveals that his voyage on the Indiaman took place after he had just finished serving in the army in India.

> "On my homeward steamer",

he writes,

> "I made friends with the most brilliant man in journalism I have ever met".

He was in the saloon of the ship and working on a book called *The River War* in which he was writing about Sudanese history:

> "From being a mere chronicle of the Omdurman campaign, it grew backwards into what was almost a history of the ruin and rescue of the Soudan".

Just as he was describing an exciting event in his historical account, he was interrupted by the aforementioned journalist,

> "Mr. G. W. Steevens [who] was the 'star' writer of a certain Mr. Harmsworth's new paper called the Daily Mail".

The comma usage in your query sentence has been efficiently explained by Roaring Fish in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

1) The style of the time for punctuation is what is called a "closed" style, meaning just about everything that even feels like a clause will be punctuated as such. (Not as closed as, say, it would have been 100 or more years earlier, but more than we would find acceptable today, perhaps.) That said, a shift in tense would be a still more obvious marker for someone of Churchill's stylistic bent.

2) "I was working" (continuous) can express any range from a moment ago to the beginning of the speaker's life. "[I] had reached" nails it down to a specific context within that range.

I would read that as meaning Churchill had been working (on his own writing, not as an employee) in the saloon of the steamer (an "Indiaman" because it transited to and from India) and, in the course of his writing, got to an exciting point in his story.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why "and had reached an exciting point in my story" does *not* precede Churchill's working in a saloon?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I believe Robusto is saying that while Churchill was working (i.e. writing his book) in the saloon of the Indiaman, he reached an exciting point *in the story he was writing about himself*.  :)

Comment: @ErikKowal careful rereading, Robusto is saying that Churchill's act of writing of his story preceded his employment in the saloon. *Churchill had been working (on his own writing....)*

Comment: @Mari-LouA - The insufficiency of context in the OP's question is the basic problem here. Consulting pp. 211-213 of the [full text of Churchill's memoir](http://archive.org/stream/rovingcommissino001321mbp/rovingcommissino001321mbp_djvu.txt) reveals that Churchill was aboard the ship and writing a history book called *The River War*, about an aspect of Sudanese history. Just as he was describing an exciting event in his historical account, he was interrupted by "Mr. G. W. Steevens [who] was the 'star' writer of a certain Mr. Harmsworth's new paper called the Daily Mail".

Comment: @ErikKowal you should post that as part of an answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - You are working me hard today, Miss...  :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I am not saying he was employed by a saloon. One meaning of saloon is simply "an eating and social area aboard a ship." Churchill used the space presumably because he more comfortable than his cabin to do his writing.

Comment: I completely misunderstood the OP's quote, it seemed Churchill once worked in a saloon. I did think it a bit strange, a saloon of all places but maybe he was in his early twenties at the time. Stranger things have been known to have happened. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Should read ". . . because he **found it** more comfortable . . ." Stupid fingers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! It helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

Punctuation is a rather subjective area - some like lots of it and some prefer a minimalist approach.

Answering your first question... I too would put a comma before "and had reached". I would justify it by saying there are two pieces of information, essentially two sentences:

*"I was working in the saloon of the Indiaman. I had reached an exciting point in my story."*

As they are two items of information glued together with an "and", they should also be separated by a comma. Effectively, a comma separated list of two items.

Your second question... they happened at the same time. "I was working in the saloon" is background information that was in progress at the time, and "reached an exciting point" is the main information that happened while he was working in the saloon.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why "and had reached an exciting point in my story" does *not* precede Churchill's working in a saloon?

Comment: @Mari-LouA ~ this rather depends on what you mean by 'precede'. If you mean working in the saloon started before the exciting part was reached, then yes- it almost certainly did but we don't know or care how long before. What we are interested in is that it was still continuing when it got exciting. If you mean that working in the saloon started and finished before the exciting bit was reached, we know that is not the case because it simply wouldn't make sense. It would mean that he wasn't working in the saloon when the exciting part of the working was reached, and that cannot be true.